# Provision Concurrency not keeping AWS Lambda function warm

Tags: concurrency, aws-lambda

I came across with Lambda new feature called "Provisioned Concurrency": End of Cold Start. First invocation will always a cold start as expected later for subsequent request it has to be warm and initialized but in the console I can see "Init Duration" for the second request which was invoked after 10 minutes. As per provisioned concurrency, Lambda has to be warm and no initialization should be done after first invocation.

X-ray details for subsequent calls
[image]

[image]